# events.js:160 throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event - Error: spawn npm ENOENT

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, gulp

OS: Windows 10 Pro
Node: 6.5.0
NPM: 3.10.3
Gulp: CLI version 3.9.1

So I'm receiving the following error, only on windows, during a gulp (build) process, when firing the `runSequence` of the process. any ideas as how to resolve it?:

```html
[14:44:57] Finished 'eslint-ci' after 18 s
[14:44:57] Starting 'ava'...
events.js:160
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn npm ENOENT
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:1026:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:193:32)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:359:16)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
```

The code is as follows:

```html
import runSequence from 'run-sequence';

gulp.task('to-html', done => {
  args.production = true;
  process.env.IS_SERVERLESS = true;

  const fetch = url => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    http.get({ host: 'localhost', path: url, port: 3000 }, res => {
      // Explicitly treat incoming data as utf8 (avoids issues with multi-byte).
      res.setEncoding('utf8');
      let body = '';
      res.on('data', data => {
        body += data;
      });
      res.on('end', () => resolve(body));
    }).on('error', reject);
  });

  const moveAssets = () => {
    const assets = fs.readdirSync('build');
    fs.mkdirSync(path.join('build', 'assets'));
    assets.forEach(fileName => {
      fs.renameSync(
        path.join('build', fileName),
        path.join('build', 'assets', fileName)
      );
    });
  };

  const toHtml = () => {
    const promises = Object.keys(urls).map(url => fetch(url).then(html => {
      fs.writeFile(path.join('build', urls[url]), html);
    }));
    return Promise.all(promises);
  };

  runSequence('eslint-ci', 'ava', 'flow', 'clean', 'build', () => {
    const proc = spawn('node', ['./src/server']);
    proc.stderr.on('data', data => console.log(data.toString()));
    proc.stdout.on('data', async data => {
      data = data.toString();
      if (data.indexOf('Server started') === -1) return;
      try {
        moveAssets();
        await toHtml();
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      } finally {
        proc.kill();
        done();
        console.log('App has been rendered to /build directory.');
        console.log('OSX tip: cd build && python -m SimpleHTTPServer 3000');
      }
    });
  });
});
```

ava.js

```html
import childProcess from 'child_process';
import gulp from 'gulp';

gulp.task('ava', done => {
  childProcess
    .spawn('npm', ['run', 'ava'], { stdio: 'inherit' })
    .on('close', done);
});
```

package.json

```html
  "ava": {
    "babel": "inherit",
    "files": [
      "src/**/__test__/**/*.js"
    ],
    "source": [
      "src/**/*"
    ],
    "require": [
      "babel-register",
      "babel-polyfill"
    ]
  },
```

Comment: Looks like the problem is in your `'ava'` task, which you haven't included in your question. Could you add it in?

Comment: @henry Thanks for the headsup. Added.

Comment: I've encountered a lot of `ENOENT` errors because of permissions issues and NPM.

Comment: @inostia May I ask what exactly you did to resolve the permissions issues you encountered with npm?

Comment: Looks like you need to keep drilling. What is `child_process`? If whatever `spawn()` is (does it `require('gulp-spawn')`?) follows the gulp convention of logging `Starting 'task'...` then we'd expect to see `Starting 'npm'...` if gulp made it past `childProcess`.

Comment: @TheoG https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions

Comment: @inostia Unfortunately, running `icacls npm /grant :f` on `C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\`, did Not resolve the issue.

Comment: @henry child_process is described here `https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html`

Comment: Have you determined whether the `'ava'` task gets as far as the `spawn()` step? It's usually possible to pinpoint a breaking point without needing to understand *why* it's breaking (e.g. comment things out, sprinkle things like `console.log('made it this far!')` around, etc), and then we'll be able to jump in and figure out what's going wrong

Comment: Don't know if your `spawn()` is calling `gulp-spawn`, but if so it looks like you might need to add `cmd:` etc to your syntax https://github.com/hparra/gulp-spawn